# Vlookup from one SharePoint Excel file to a Table in another SharePoint Excel File ERROR

Tags: excel, excel-formula, sharepoint, sharepoint-online, excel-tables

I have 2 Excel spreadsheets, both saved in SharePoint.  Both are saved in the same folder. I can write a normal `VLOOKUP` from one to other, and this will work fine.

```
=VLOOKUP(B5,
'https://xxxxx.sharepoint.com/sites/MY-SITE/
 Documents/Testing Folder/[Master File.xlsx]Data'!$A:$F,3,0)
```

However, the Data sheet in the Master File is actually a table called "Table_Data" and so I want the VLOOKUP to reference the Table and not the relative column letter.  Something like:

```
=VLOOKUP(B5,'https://xxxxx.sharepoint.com/sites/
 MY-SITE/Documents/Testing Folder/
 Master File.xlsx'!Table_Data[#All],3,0)
```

But this gives me a `#REF` Error.  How can I get the `VLOOKUP` to reference the table in the other workbook?

Comment: Don't think it will work, i have tried this using `Structured References` in Sharepoint, but it returns `#Ref` error.

Comment: If it's working with the first method, why change it? Will people re-arrange the columns? If they do that, will the lookup column be guaranteed to stay in the first place?

Comment: What I'm actually going to use is XLOOKUP, which I prefer because you specify a column name and can look at the formula and know exactly what data is being brought through - whereas it's time consuming using VLOOKUP to find out what column E is, when you revisit spreadsheets x months later.  It's all about efficiency and making things easy to interpret.